# Get zipcode inside track.phtml to track shipment of a order

Tags: orders, order-status, shipment, shipment-tracking

How can I get the zipcode of the order inside the track.html file?

I tried this, but that does not work:

```
<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getShippingAddress()->getPostcode()) ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The block type of the `track.phtml` template is `core/template` so it's default without a method like `$this->getShippingMethod()`.

If you check the `shipment_new.html` email template somewhere around the bottom the tracking block is included with the following statement

```
{{block type='core/template' area='frontend' template='email/order/shipment/track.phtml' shipment=$shipment order=$order}}
```

This means both the *order* and *shipment* are available in the data of the block class. Which means you can do this

```
<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getOrder()->getShippingAddress()->getPostcode()) ?>
```